# Monitors not detected after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, monitor

I've recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 to my PC.  I've have Windows 7 on it as well.  When I first started up Ubuntu, it detected both of my monitors.  I then updated the drivers and restarted, but when I restarted, Ubuntu doesn't detect the monitors anymore.  I've removed and reinstalled the drivers but that doesn't work.  Whenever I boot in Windows 7, Windows still detects both monitors, so I know it's not the cables.  It has to be the drivers or Ubuntu.  My question is, What do I need to do to get this fixed? I'm new to Linux by the way.

Display adapters: NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GTS 512.

I went to System Settings/Additional Drivers and then activated NVIDIA accelerated Graphics driver (version current) [Recommended]

Answer (score 1):

After you install the nvidia drivers you have to explicitly configure multi monitors with the Nvidia tool (which is different from the built in tool).

Hit the ubuntu button, and search for "nvidia", and then click on it, and then go to the multimonitor section and configure them how you want:

[image]